# Serializable Errors with Java Object

Tags: java, android, serialization, opengl-es-2.0

**Edit, Here's how i solved using the comments**
So after trying different ways of serializing and looking through my code, I finally found out that each object drawn in the renderer contains FloatBuffers.  I created a capsule class thanks to Ted Hopp.  Then I tried returning the float representation of the FloatBuffers using .array(), which you can't do.  My guess is because these are running on threads.  So using a suggestion from Learn OpenGL ES to use get, i instead did

```
public float[] getVertexBuffer()
{
    float[] local = new float[vertexBuffer.capacity()];
    vertexBuffer.get(local);
    return local;
}
```

Which does work and returns the float[].

Then i store them all in a capsule object for each mGrid object i created

```
        Encapsulate capsule = new Encapsulate(values);
        for(int i = 0; i < values[0]; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < values[1]; j++)
            {
                capsule.storeVertex(i,j,mRenderer.mGrid[i*values[1] + j].getVertexBuffer());
                capsule.storeColors(i,j,mRenderer.mGrid[i*values[1] + j].getmColors());
                capsule.storePillar(i,j,mRenderer.mGrid[i*values[1] + j].getPillarPositions());
            }
        }
```

Which I can then ultimately save because it's serializable.  Thank you all

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**
So i'm trying to save a GLSurfaceView object, whose class is denoted as

```
class GLWorld extends GLSurfaceView implements Serializable
```

Now I'm sure as i do the saving correctly.

```
public void saveSimulation()
{
    String fileName = "Test Save";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(mGLView);
        Log.d("Save","Successfully Written");
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Save","File not found exception");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Save","IO exception");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    finish();
}
```

But i'm getting an error i have no clue how to fix.  I've spent hours looking around but haven't found anything like it.

09-16 17:36:50.639: W/System.err(2996): java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.FloatToByteBufferAdapter

Along with many more system err lines below that, which i believe stem from this one error.

My GLWorld creates a renderer object in it which has different objects with floatbuffers in it which store vertex and color data.  I can't figure out what to do to get past this error, or why those float buffers are throwing an error.  Everything runs smoothly except actually trying to save this GLWorld object and it's driving me insane.

Comment: Nice to see it works now. :) For future readers: 1) FloatBuffer.array() is optional so it only works if the FloatBuffer is directly backed by a Java array. In this case, it was created with allocateDirect() so the backing memory store is located in the native heap, so that's why we need to call .get(). 2) One must be careful when accessing data between threads. GLSurfaceView.queueEvent() can be used to dispatch calls to the GL thread so that only the GL thread messes with the buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declaring that a class `implements Serializable` is not enough to successfully serialize objects of that class. The default implementation requires that *every field* of the class be serializable. In your case, there's a field of type `FloatToByteBufferAdapter` that isn't serializable (there may be more).

You can define your own serialization mechanism to serialize only what you need. The details can be found in the [`Serializable` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Be aware that by subclassing `GLSurfaceView`, it is unlikely you will be able to successfully deserialize this class, even if you write the correct support methods. For one thing, `GLSurfaceView` does not have a default (no-arg) constructor, which is a requirement of Java's serialization mechanism. Also, many objects simply cannot be serialized (e.g., streams).

I suggest that you encapsulate the data you want to serialize in a helper class and limit the serialization/deserialization to those data.

Comment: If encapsulate, and save.  Later when i load that object, will i still have the exact same render world that i saved.  Or will it reset itself?  Because what i'm really wanting to save is my renderer that's been created.  Because maybe then if that's the case, i can just save the renderer in a method inside the GLWorld class

Comment: I think this answer is complete enough that I don't really have much to add. Ion, maybe what you can do is just encapsulate all of the user state into plain Java objects and just serialize those. When you want to restore the state, just recreate the GLSurfaceView and then restore the state that you need to.

Comment: @Ion - If you can make your renderer implement `Serializable`, I think you can do what you want. It depends on what data your renderer implementation contains. You obviously won't get the identical object back, but you probably don't really want that anyway; the renderer needs to re-initialize all OpenGL resources whenever the EGL context is lost and recreated.

Comment: Really the meat i'm trying to save is this part inside my onDrawFrame(...) [PASTEBIN LINK](http://pastebin.com/kRMRqdnD).  But since mGrid is only one variable being manipulated.  If i try to save mGrid, won't i have to go through that for loop again to recreate everything.  Thus no values inside of it are actually saved.  (That randomization of values you see is very important, and after that each one is going to further be different and unique).  Could i convert that mGrid into an array instead and then store that array? then each element would be preserved i would think.

Comment: @Ion - From what I can tell you simply need to serialize and recover a single `double[] pillarHeights` array. Primitive arrays are inherently serializable; you can simply write the array and read it back in at the appropriate times. Just separate out the code for populating the `pillarHeights` array with random numbers from the code for initializing the `GridSquare` objects. Those can be reconstructed once the `pillarHeights` array is deserialized.

Comment: those pillar heights are for initialization, they modify variables inside mGrid, so i need to save each mGrid.  Because those variables in mGrid change later depending on the initialization

Comment: So if i create an array of GridSquare objects, GridSquare doesn't extend/implement anything so everything should be storeable right?  I also appreciate you keeping responding, i know some would just move on.

Comment: @Ion - That's correct. If every field in `GridSquare` is implicitly serializable or is an object that (correctly) implements `Serializable`, then you can simply declare `GridSquare implements Serializable` and save/restore it to object streams.

Comment: Alright, i will try this.  Thank you very much for helping me concretely figure out what i need to do!

Answer (score 0):

Gotta assume that something within the mGLView inheritance contains FloatTOByteBufferAdapter, which isn't serializable.

Comment: This offers a suggestion on where to look, but not really a complete answer. This would be more appropriate as a comment to the main question.

Comment: Was meant to be, I thought I clicked comment add comment :)